# Typing "exit" closes foo.exe along with powershell

Tags: powershell, command-prompt

I set the path to a program, say "foo.exe", to my system path and so typing foo in cmd/powershell starts the program. However when I type exit to get out of cmd/powershell foo.exe also closes with it. Why does this happen and how do I prevent this from happening?

This doesn't happen for all programs, only certain ones which means those certain ones should be added to path in a different way probably or should be started in a different way I'm guessing. However, searching over the internet for a long time didn't give me anything so a little help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If `foo.exe` is a *console* application (one compiled for the Windows console subsystem), it will run *synchronously* in `cmd.exe` / PowerShell: that is, control won't be returned to the calling shell until the application exits. This means that you won't even get a chance to type `exit` until `foo.exe` has already exited.

  - However, it *is* possible to run a console application *asynchronously*, namely  if you use a *job* to run it, via [`Start-Job`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/Start-Job) or [`Start-ThreadJob`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/ThreadJob/Start-ThreadJob); that is, `foo.exe` will then run in the *background*.

    - In that event, exiting the calling shell with `exit` *will* terminate the `foo.exe` process.
    - To prevent that, you can use the [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Start-Process) cmdlet instead; on Windows, you can use it to launch `foo.exe` directly, which will open in a *new console window* by default; on Unix-like platforms, you must launch it via the `nohup` utility (which sends the program's output to a file named `nohup.out` in the current directory).
- By contrast, if `foo.exe` is a *GUI*-subsystem application, it launches *asynchronously* and *independently* of the calling shell: that is, control returns to the calling shell right after successful *creation* of the new process, and exiting the shell has no effect on that new process.